# How to perform analysis of non-stationary and unevenly spaced time series?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, unevenly-spaced-time-series

It is very easy to apply **ACF** (autocorrelation function) to time series in order to investigate the similarity between observations as a function of the time lag between them.
However, ACF only works with stationary and evenly spaced time series.
In my case, I need to analyze time series which lacks both these two properties.

Even going to the frequency domain is not enough. The **Lomb–Scargle Fourier** transform is a partial solution: it does not require equale samples in the signal, but it does require stationarity.

Do you know any approaches that could help?

Comment: Could you provide more information regarding your input time-series? Most time-series are not perfectly equidistant yet the variance can sometimes be neglected.

Comment: Sure @NikolasRieble. My data is earthquake data and I want to analyze several time series linked to it (magnitude, inter-event distance and so on).
As far as I know, earthquake data is the typical example of a non-stationary and unevenly spaced time series.

Comment: I am not familiar with earthquake data. Can you provide a link to an exemplar dataset?

Comment: Well, a typical dataset includes several measurements for each event (magnitude, time, location and so on). If you want, you can download a dataset from this [link](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/csv.php).
I found something really useful at this [link](https://it.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/cwt.html) from Matlab, based on Kobe earthquake (bottom of the page). It is used as an example for the application of the CWT method, which could be a solution to my problem. The point is that I cannot figure out how to link it to the ACF analysis !

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to investigate the relation between a) the distance in time of two earthquakes and b) the similarity of both earthquakes? If so, I doubt that time-series analysis is the right way to go.

Comment: I would like to investigate the similarity between observations as a function of the time lag between them. These observations could be the time of the single events, or the (spatial) inter-event distance (for the latter, the question is: is the distance between event 1 and 2 somehow related to distance between event 2 and 3?)

Comment: The similarity of the observations is not a time-series similarity, since the observation itself does not contain a time-series, which is why i deleted from previous answer. As my limited knowledge is mostly restricted to time-series similarity, I can not help you.